# FB: Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I grant an object a "likes" connection, as per fb requirements?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Facebook Graph API to publish a like on behalf of a user. For how it is done, refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing.